# Does the derivative of $\arctan(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2} = \cos^2(y)$, where $x = \tan(y)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse-function

I know the derivative of $\arctan(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and the derivative of $\tan(x) = \frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}$. But, I recently read somewhere that the derivative of the inverse function is the reciprocal of the derivative. So the derivative of $\arctan(x) = \cos^2(y)$, where $x = \tan(y)$. Does this hold? I played around with some numbers and it seems it works.

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable at $x$, and $f'(x) \neq 0$, then $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $y := f(x)$ and $(f^{-1})'(y) = 1/f'(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you differentiate a function depending on $x$, the answer should also be a function depending on $x$. You have:\begin{align}\arctan'(x)&=\frac1{\tan'(\arctan x)}\\&=\frac1{^\frac1{\cos^2(\arctan x)}}\\&=\frac1{1+\tan^2(\arctan x)}\text{ (because $\frac1{\cos^2\theta}=1+\tan^2\theta$)}\\&=\frac1{1+x^2}.\end{align}In the general case, we have$$(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac1{f'\bigl(f^{-1}(x)\bigr)}.$$

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your response. After the second equality, doesn't $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{cos^2(arctan(x))}} = cos^2(arctan(x)) = cos^2(y)$?

Comment: The derivative of a function of $x$ must always be another function of $x$.

Comment: @beginner Yes, that is correct. However, read the other comment.

Comment: Thank you both!

Comment: What ?? If $x=\tan(y)$, then $\dfrac1{1+x^2}=\cos^2(y)$, undisputably ! By the way, this is independent of the derivative of the arc tangent.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I agree, but the goal was to compute $\arctan'(x)$. So, the answer should be a function depending on $x$.

Comment: Sorry but I still disagree, this is said nowhere. And if $x=\tan(y)$, $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=(\arctan(x))'=\cos^2(y)$ is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

If $x = \tan(y)$, then
$$\cos^2(y) = \frac1{\sec^2(y)} = \frac1{1+\tan^2(y)} = \frac1{1+x^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You are right,
$$(\arctan(x))'=\frac1{1+x^2}$$ is true and if $x=\tan(y)$,

$$\frac1{1+x^2}=\cos^2(y)$$ as well.

You can also write

$$(\arctan(x))'=\cos^2(\arctan(x)).$$

---

Now if you write

$$y'=\cos^2(y),$$ this is an ordinary differential equation, which is autonomous, and is satisfied by

$$y=\arctan(x+c).$$